# MySQL - Getting Two Different Results (PHP and phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run a SQL query, and it is working correctly in phpMyAdmin, but whe running it in PHP, the query comes back very wonky. The following query yields two different results:

```
SELECT `stock_ticker`, `stock_simpleName`, `stock_logo` 
FROM `stocks` 
WHERE stock_simpleName REGEXP'^c'
```

I get the following results in phpMyAdmin (Which is correct):

```
stock_simpleName
----------------------
Coca-Cola
Campbell's
ConAgra Foods
```

However, in PHP it comes out really weird:

```
stock_simpleName
-----------------------
Coca-Cola
MasterCard
Campbell's
Microsoft
The Walt Disney Company
PepsiCo
The Hershey Company
Proctor & Gamble
ConAgra Foods
...etc...
```

Why is this happening? This doesn't make any sense. Is it due to a server setting in PHP or some form of encoding or whatnot?

---

### EDIT:

Here is my PHP Code:

The sub-model class (the creator of the pieces):

```
public function allOtherSearchResults($query, $dontQuery = null) {

    $name = "stocks";
    $where = "stock_simpleName REGEXP'^" . $query . "'";
    $cols = array("stock_ticker", "stock_simpleName", "stock_logo");
    $limit = 5;

    return $this->select($name, $cols, $where, $limit);

}
```

The main-model class (this runs the query):

```
public function select($tableName, $columns, $where = null, $limit = null) {

    global $purifier;

    // Make columns SQL friendly
    $cols = "`";
    $cols .= implode("`, `", $columns);
    $cols .= "`";

    $table = "`" . $tableName . "`";

    if (!empty($where)) {

        $where = " WHERE " . $where;

    }

    // Check limit
    if (!empty($limit)) {

        $limit = " LIMIT $limit";

    }

    // SQL CODE
    $sql = "SELECT " . $cols . " FROM " . $table . $where . $limit;

    // SQL DEBUGGING IF CODE RETURNS BOOLEAN ERROR
    echo $sql . "<br>";

    $query = $this->conn->query($sql);

    // Store the value in a variable called table with an array of that table's name followed by it's values
    // EX: $model->table["bands"]["band_name"]
    //
    // Accessible by the individual page/directory's controller's

    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

        // Store values as $model->table["tableName"]["columnName"]["index (usually 0)"]
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $this->data[$tableName][$key][] = $row[$key];
        }

    }


    // Loop through results to clean them
    // Foreach loops through each column
    // Make sure the table isn't empty (i.e. login returns an error)
    if (!empty($this->data[$tableName])) {
        foreach ($this->data[$tableName] as $key => $tableArray) {

            // For loop goes through each value in a certain row
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($tableArray); $i++) {
                // Convert from data variable to table after HTML PURIFIER
                $this->table[$tableName][$key][$i] = $purifier->purify($tableArray[$i]);
            }

        }
    }


    // Declare the array after loop has finished for use in view
    $this->table;

    if (!empty($this->table)) {

        return true;

    }

}
```

And it gives me the same SQL output as above. I am not sure if there is a different interpretation of certain characters in PHP versus the standard MySQL in phpMyAdmin. Has anyone even had this problem before?

Comment: Have you tried using LIKE ?
WHERE stock_simpleName LIKE 'C%'

Comment: show your php code plase

Comment: @ArmandoSM I have tried many different queries. They all work in MYSQL, they just don't work when PHP calls the code. I keep getting random results in return.

Comment: What does `echo $sql` show you?

Comment: @Mureinik It shows me the same code I have at the beginning of the answer. I have it normally commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, that there is a problem wiht `^` character.
Try to set proper connection & result encoding, eq.

```
$this->conn->query("MYSQL SET NAMES utf8");
$this->conn->query("MYSQL SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Also, check if your php script file is saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Moreover, you should consider of using prepared statement (even to prevent SQL Injection):

```
$this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `stocks` WHERE `stock_simpleName` REGEXP ?");
$this->conn->bind_param("s", "^c");
$this->conn->execute();
$query = $this->conn->get_result();
```

Comment: Well I guess you are right, `^` is in deed basic ASCII character, but do you have any other idea what could cause this kind of a problem?